# Why are sets like $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}|-\pi < x < \pi\}$ both closed and open in $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't quite fully understand why $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}|-\pi < x < \pi\}$ is both open and closed.

I can see that you cannot place any ball around any element within this set without incorporating an element not in $\mathbb{Q}$, since there is a irrational between every rational.

However, how would you prove this set is open?

A set is open if every open ball of some radius $r > 0$ around an element is in the set, but intuitively no ball can be found. Thus it could only mean  $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}|-\pi < x < \pi\}$ is closed?

Can someone help!

Comment: Are you considering the set in question as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the induced/subspace topology?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese No I don't know about topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The topology of $Q$ is induced the topology of $R$ so a subset of $Q$ of the form $U\cap Q$ $U$ open in $R$ is open and a subset of $Q$ of the form $F\cap Q$ $F$ closed in $R$ is closed so if $u$ is irrational, $[-u,u]\cap Q=(-u,u)\cap Q$ is open and closed.

Comment: But clearly we cannot place any ball around any element of the set without incorporating something from outside of the set. i.e. $x \in S$ there exists $r > 0$ s.t. $\|x - y\|_2 < r$ for some $y \in S$.  So how can it be open?

Comment: @FemaleTank, There are two different topologies being discussed. One is "balls contain all the real numbers they should", but the other, the one in which the set is both open and closed, is "we only include the rational numbers in any considerations".

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful about terminology here. This set is *not* open *or* closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. It is open as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ because it is an open ball in this space. (This sounds circular, but the two instances of the word "open" are defined differently here.) It's also closed as a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ because if you have a sequence of rational numbers in this set which converges *to a rational number*, then the limit is in this set.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{x\in\mathbb{Q}|-\pi < x < \pi \} = \mathbb{Q}\cap [-\pi,\pi].$$
Since $[-\pi, \pi]$ is closed in the reals, the intersection witih $\mathbb{Q}$ is relatively closed in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Hi how does this mess up with my intuition about placing open balls? The set is open then for each $x \in S$ there exists $r > 0$ s.t. $\|x - y\|_2 < r$ for some $y \in S$